# How to install ODBC Driver 17 in a docker image based on windows server core?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I'm setting up a new docker windows servercore image for my application. Data access uses [ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567). I need to install this on the image so in my `Dockerfile` I included the following:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016

COPY msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi c:\\msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi

RUN msiexec.exe /i C:\\msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi /norestart /qn IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES
...
```

When I run `docker build...` I get the following error

```
The command 'cmd /S /C msiexec.exe /i C:\\msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi /norestart /qn IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES' returned a non-zero code: 1603
```

Code `1603` indicates that a restart is required.

I'm not sure how an image can be restarted. How do I proceed ahead with this? Without the driver, I won't be able to get my application running.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I ran the MSI manually in the container with logging enabled. It turns out that the failure was occurring due to missing VC++ redistributable.

So, I updated the `Dockerfile` by adding a line to copy and install [`vc_redist.x64.exe`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) which fixed the issue for me.

Snippet from the `Dockerfile` that solved the problem for me.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2
COPY vc_redist.x64.exe c:/ \
     msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi c:/
RUN c:\\vc_redist.x64.exe /install /passive /norestart 
RUN msiexec.exe /i C:\\msodbcsql_17.3.1.1_x64.msi /norestart /qn /quiet /passive IACCEPTMSODBCSQLLICENSETERMS=YES 

...
```

Just posting this answer here in case someone else stumbles upon the same issue.

Comment: Can you share the resulted `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @PieterMeiresone, I updated the answer with the relevant portion from the Dockerfile. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am not familiar with installing executables in powershell so all bits help.

Comment: what switch did you use to get the log file ?

Comment: @Choco follow the guidance on this page https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html

Comment: How did you end up setting up the configuration for the ODBC driver later on once you got this working?  Have any finished dockerfile with the functioning ODBC Driver install available for those of us who are finding this years later?

Comment: @bubthegreat, The specific ODBC driver version was a requirement of the software that I wanted to install on the docker image. But in case you want to setup DSN, you can do so by making registry entries.